# Adding summary statistics labels to box plot using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add labels to sit above box plots. For example, in this example, instead of NA, I would want the label above A to say "total number of var3 = 11" and over B "total number of var3 = 34". In my real data, numbers are produced, but they bear no relation to the original data set (I cannot work out how they could possibly be calculated from the original data, so I must be doing something wrong!).

```
var1<- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B")
var2<- as.numeric(c(4:12))
var3<- as.numeric(c(1:9))

df<- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

stat_box_data <- function(y, upper_limit = max(df$var2) * 1.15 ) {
  return( 
    data.frame(
      y = 0.95* upper_limit,
      label = paste('number of var1 =', length(y), '\n', 
                    'total number of var3 =', sum(df$var3[y])
      )
    )
  )
}

ggplot(df, aes(var1, var2)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(    fun.data = stat_box_data, 
                   geom = "text", 
                   hjust = 0.5,
                   vjust = 0.9)

df%>% group_by (var1) %>% summarise (sum = sum(var3))
```

[Link to graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN8cn.png)

Thanks to original post for code here https://gscheithauer.medium.com/how-to-add-number-of-observations-to-a-ggplot2-boxplot-b22710f7ef80

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand where you are getting the numbers 11 and 34 from? You can just manually put them in if you really wanted those exact numbers?

Comment: They are the sum var3 for each of A and B. I would be grateful to know how to put them in manually although I want to be able to do this for a graph with ore than 2 box plots in it so if there is a way of automating it that would be great

Comment: As a remark, you can use `y = Inf` instead of `y = 0.95* upper_limit`.

Comment: @pcompston I was hoping someone would come along to answer your question because I was curious to see what they come up with. I saw not on answered so I just added in what I was initially thinking

Answer (score 0):

You could get the result you want using this rather convoluted method.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
var1<- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B")
var2<- as.numeric(c(4:12))
var3<- as.numeric(c(1:9))

df<- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

stat_box_data <- function(y,  upper_limit = max(df$var2) * 1.15) {
  
  return( 
    data.frame(
      y = 0.95* upper_limit,label = paste('count =', length(y), '\n',
                                          'mean =', sum(df$var3[match(y, df$var2)]), '\n'
      )
    )
  )
}

d<-df%>% group_by (var1) %>% summarise (sum = sum(var3)) %>% pull(sum)

ggplot(df, aes(var1, var2)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = stat_box_data,
                   geom = "text", 
                   hjust = 0.5,
                   vjust = 0.9)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. It isn't working on my larger data set though, I am still getting random numbers computed. I'm curious about the line `d<-df%>% group_by (var1) %>% summarise (sum = sum(var3)) %>% pull(sum)`  - where is this used in the plot code?

Comment: Sorry, that isn't being user im the posted, it's a remnant of something I was trying.

Comment: Please remove `d<-df%>% group_by (var1) %>% summarise (sum = sum(var3)) %>% pull(sum)`